# Calculating the php current time by timezone

Tags: php

**Background**

I am making some updated to a PHP application that is very old. In the application there was an error being thrown because the use of a depreciated function `mktime()`. I updated this function across the application with `time()` instead. Once I did this I noticed that when the local time for a user which is calculated by their zip code is displayed, it is one hour behind the actual local time.

I have tracked the time calculation to a function which is below. The time is passed into the value of, `$client["localtime"]`

**Example Code**

```
if (isset($time) && $time) {
    $utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
    $utc = strtotime($utc_str);
    if (isset($tznames[ $time["timezone"] ])) {
        $client["timezone"] = $tznames[ $time["timezone"] ];
    } else {
        $client["timezone"] = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($time["daylightsavings"] == "Y" && date("I")) {
        $time["timezone"]--;
    }
    $client["localtime"] = date("g:ia", $utc - ($time["timezone"] * 3600));
} else {
    $client["localtime"] = "Unknown";
    $client["timezone"] = "Unknown";
}
```

**Question**

Why is this showing the local time for the client's timezone behind by 1 hour and what must I do to fix it?

Comment: What does "timezone" mean here? Looks like that "timezone" is actually a numeric *UTC offset*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($time) && $time) { 
    $utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
    $utc = strtotime($utc_str);
    if (isset($tznames[$time["timezone"]])) { $client["timezone"] = $tznames[$time["timezone"]]; } 
    else { $client["timezone"] = "Unknown"; }
    if ($time["daylightsavings"] == "Y" && date("I")) { $time["timezone"]--; }



   // print_r(($time["timezone"] * 3600).",".$client["timezone"].",".$time["timezone"].",".$utc_str.",".$utc);
       $client["localtime"] = date("g:ia", $utc - ($time["timezone"] * 3600 - 3600));
} else { $client["localtime"] = "Unknown";
$client["timezone"] = "Unknown";}
```

Check the above code I have subtracted the 3600 from  so that it show 1hour late please check if it will work

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
function convertTimeByTimezone($datetime,$timezone='Asia/Kolkata') {
        $given = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $given->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
        $output = $given->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
        return $output;
}
```

Comment: It is necessary that I understand why this function dos not work when changed from mktime(0 to time() and then fix it. Thank you though. I do know I can write a new function but the point of this is to understand the change so i can make minimal changes to the code in the app to keep it working globally and understand the things that break when depreciated function are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Australia/Adelaide'));
echo 'Australia/Adelaide: '.$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date1 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo 'America/Chicago: '. $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```